# What is the problem with working jquery with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am working with Laravel 5.8 and I have installed Bootstrap 4 using NPM and Laravel mix. My webpack.mix.js is like this

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.autoload({
  jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
  'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js': ['Popper']
})
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts', 'public/webfonts');
```

My package.json is like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19",
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
  "cross-env": "^5.1",
  "jquery": "^3.5.1",
  "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
  "lodash": "^4.17.13",
  "popper.js": "^1.12",
  "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
  "sass": "^1.15.2",
  "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
  "vue": "^2.5.17",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
},
```

I have following jQuery code to work toggle button in the blade file and it is extends with app.blade.php file as well.

```
<script>
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });
</script>
```

The toggle button is not working. I have the following error message in the browser console:

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template: Templates should only be
> responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with
> side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.
> You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to turn on
> production mode when deploying for production. See more tips at
> https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html Source map error: Error:
> request failed with status 404 Resource URL:
> http://localhost:8000/js/app.js Source Map URL: popper.js.map

How could I fix this matter?